# elasticsearch : boosting documents in has_parent query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to boost the docs that "come" from the `has_parent` query ?

```
{
  "query": {
      "function_score": {
          "query": {
              "bool": {
                  "should": [
                      {
                          "multi_match": {
                              "fields": ["name^3", "tags^2", "content"],
                              "query": "xx"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "has_parent": {
                              "type": "theparent",
                              "query": {
                                  "multi_match": {
                                      "type": "best_fields",
                                      "fields": ["name^5", "content"],
                                      "query": "xx"
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "has_child": {
                              "type": "thechild",
                              "query": {
                                  "multi_match": {
                                      "fields": ["name^3","content"],
                                      "query": "xx"
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          },
          "score_mode": "sum",
          "functions": [
              {
                  "linear": {
                      "date": {
                          "origin": "2014-08-29",
                          "scale": "700d",
                          "decay": 0.6
                      }
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  }
```

More exactly, I would like to boost those docs only when the query matches the name field of the parent 
(I haven't found a way to refer to a parent field in the `functions` i.e. `theparent._source.name ~= "xx"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [sources from Github (see line 104)](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/v1.3.2/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/HasParentQueryParser.java), the `boost` parameter is allowed within a `has_parent` query.

Based on this attribute, you can boost specifically the `should` clause containing the `has_parent` query. In your case, the result would be :

```
...
                  {
                      "has_parent": {
                          "type": "theparent",
                          "query": {
                              "multi_match": {
                                  "type": "best_fields",
                                  "fields": ["name^5", "content"],
                                  "query": "xx"
                              }
                          },
                          "boost": 5
                      }
                  }
...
```

I don't know if it can help you, but you will find more insights about boosting query clauses [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html).

Comment: You re right. I had put the boost param at the wrong level.